# When I press render, my object changes

Tags: rendering

[image]

I am trying to render this scene above [Snap-shot 1]. But when i am trying to render the scene, its showing me the result [Snap-shot 2]. Whats wrong with my blender [2.72]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have provided the correct images? Because they both look the same, or is that your problem?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. I dont touch anything. But after pressing render, meshes are not staying right position.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably have keyframes set for your objects. If you have set a keyframe for an object and then you move it without overwriting the keyframe, the animated property gets reset on render.

To fix this issue move the object into the desired position and press <kbd>I</kbd>. Select `LocRotScale` to set the location, the rotation and the scale.

When you render the scene now, there should be no more problems with moving objects.

Comment: Thank you. My auto key was on, I didn't know, its on.